# Lista no reconoce indice

Tags: python

No logro entender porque no reconoce el índice de la lista, como se ve en el print esta bien segmentado con comas, pero de todas formas no reconoce y al intentar mas abajo la consulta puesta como comentario me indica que esta fuera del rango de la lista (IndexError: list index out of range)
Si pongo un "subíndice" (regisp[0][1] por ejemplo)no se como llamarle, me empieza a marcar letra por letra hasta agotar el índice 0, el índice 1 esta vacío supuestamente y el índice 2 marca que excede el limite

```
import requests
import json

url="https://chilealerta.com/api/query/?user=demo&select=ultimos_sismos&country=chile"
respuesta=requests.get(url)

class Sismos():
    def ObtenerSismos():
        if(respuesta.status_code==200):
            print("Acceso Permitido")
            datosSismos=json.loads(respuesta.text.encode("utf-8"))
            newArray=[]
            for recorrer in datosSismos['ultimos_sismos_chile']:
             regi=("Fecha : {} | Referencia : {}| Magnitud : {} | ID : {}{}".format(recorrer['chilean_time'],recorrer['reference'],recorrer['magnitude'],recorrer['id'],"||"))
             regisp=regi.split("||")
             for v in regisp:
               newArray.append(v)
             print(newArray)
             #print(newArray[2])


Sismos.ObtenerSismos()
```

Esto sale por consola:

```
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '']     
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Referencia : 71 km al SO de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Referencia : 71 km al SO de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 03:41:29 | Referencia : 239 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 5.6 | ID : 41177912', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Referencia : 71 km al SO de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 03:41:29 | Referencia : 239 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 5.6 | ID : 41177912', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 19:00:14 
| Referencia : 117 km al NE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 79854050', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Referencia : 71 km al SO de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 03:41:29 | Referencia : 239 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 5.6 | ID : 41177912', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 19:00:14 
| Referencia : 117 km al NE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 79854050', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 05:06:26 | Referencia : Off the coast of Aisen - Chile| Magnitud : 4.8 | 
ID : 79885673', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Referencia : 71 km al SO de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 03:41:29 | Referencia : 239 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 5.6 | ID : 41177912', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 19:00:14 
| Referencia : 117 km al NE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 79854050', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 05:06:26 | Referencia : Off the coast of Aisen - Chile| Magnitud : 4.8 | 
ID : 79885673', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/08 17:55:40 | Referencia : 139 km al SE de Arica - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 49802790', '']
['Fecha : 2022/12/22 15:27:40 | Referencia : 164 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 58827865', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Referencia : 80 km al NO de La Serena - Chile| Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Referencia : 228 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Referencia : 226 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Referencia : 227 km al SO de Coyhaique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Referencia : 184 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Referencia : 150 km al SE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Referencia : 208 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Referencia : 102 km al NE de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Referencia : 71 km al SO de Valparaíso - Chile| Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/10 03:41:29 | Referencia : 239 km al NE de Antofagasta - Chile| Magnitud : 5.6 | ID : 41177912', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 19:00:14 
| Referencia : 117 km al NE de Iquique - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 79854050', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/09 05:06:26 | Referencia : Off the coast of Aisen - Chile| Magnitud : 4.8 | 
ID : 79885673', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/08 17:55:40 | Referencia : 139 km al SE de Arica - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 49802790', '', 'Fecha : 2022/12/08 08:21:36 | Referencia : 16 km al SE de Talca - Chile| Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 11802796', '']
```

Comment: El código corre sin errores. La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cual es el resultado correcto?

Comment: El punto es que no imprime los valores segun corresponde su indice, repite los valores (todos los valores de la lista como si se compartiera el indice) aun cuando estan bien separados con comas que es como yo conozco que se separan los indices en las listas, y aparte de eso cuando se quiere buscar un indice mas alto excede el de la lista siendo que deberia mostrar mas valores de los que indica que es el tope de la lista

Comment: La forma más simple de plantear el problema es mostrar la salida esperada del programa. De paso, ¿no será `regisp=regi.split("|")`, con una sola barra?

Comment: no no, es que no es le problema donde va la coma del split, es como si no detectara las comas, porque en efecto es una lista que funciona con indices pero aun cuando estan separados no detecta el indice o no funciona tratar de operarlos de esa forma

Comment: Solo veo un `split()` y 4 comas que separan los argumentos de un `format()`. No veo donde puedas estar detectando comas.

Comment: En lo que sale por consola me refiero, eso sale al printar "newArray" esa lista es la que necesito tratar con indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pude entender muy bien tu problema, pero pienso que te refieres a obtener una lista de los valores obtenidos de los sismos de la página proporcionada. A lo cual yo dejaría el código de la siguiente manera:

```
import requests
import json

url="https://chilealerta.com/api/query/? 
user=demo&select=ultimos_sismos&country=chile"
respuesta=requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

class Sismos():

    def ObtenerSismos():

        if(respuesta.status_code==200):
            print("Acceso Permitido")
            datosSismos=json.loads(respuesta.text.encode("utf-8"))
            newArray=[]

            for recorrer in datosSismos['ultimos_sismos_chile']:
                regi=["Fecha : {} | Referencia : {}| Magnitud : {} | ID : {}".format(recorrer['chilean_time'],recorrer['reference'],recorrer['magnitude'],recorrer['id'])]
                newArray.append(regi)

        print(newArray)


Sismos.ObtenerSismos()
```

Si no es así, explícame un poco mejor el problema, esto da como salida una lista con varias listas dentro.
Por ejemplo al llamar el segundo elemento obtendrás:

```
['Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Referencia : southEste de Isla de Pascua - Chile| Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750']
```

Comment: No es aconsejable responder preguntas poco claras o confusas. La mayoría de las veces trabajas en vano, pues el OP realmente quería otra cosa.

Comment: Bueno, no este caso al menos, Disculpen si me exprese mal y agradezco al usuario que soluciono mi problema